# How to add Custom Template in Telerik MVC combobox?

Tags: combobox, telerik-mvc

Is there a way to add custom template inside Telerik MVC Combobox.?
I have a need to add checkboxes and images for each options inside combobox.
Telerik have this feature for Rad control for combobox.
How to do it in MVC control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible now with Telerik MVC extensions but it is with [KendoUI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/template.html). Since the next release of KendoUI will include MVC extensions you may want to check it that works for you